# Disable / Enable button by checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, checkbox

I want to disable my `button` if no `checkbox` is checked. At least one `checkbox` should be checked to enable the button.

My HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($clients as $client)
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="$client['id']" class="checkbox"></td>
        <td>{{ $client['name'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach    
</table>

<button type="button" id="off" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#offer" disabled>Choose New Offer</button>
```

I tried this jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.checkbox').click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('#off').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#off').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The button is `disabled` by default. When checked one checkbox it's enabled, when unchecked it's disabled again. But the problem is when I checked multiple checkbox and uncheck one checkbox it's disable again, though many checkbox is still checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to see if *any* checkbox is check to make the decision on the disabled state.

Your should also use `prop` and not `attr` to ensure cross-browser compatibility.

```
$(function () {
  $('.checkbox').click(function () {
    $('#off').prop('disabled', !$('.checkbox:checked').length);
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/L72Lv6h1/

`prop` for `disabled` can take a *boolean* flag value, so no need for the `if else`.

Comment: `$('#off').prop('disabled', $('.checkbox:checked').length > 0);` needs to be `$('#off').prop('disabled', $('.checkbox:checked').length === 0);` to fit the behavior smartrahat wants. I tried to make an edit but there's a character limit. Otherwise this is better than mine +1.

Comment: @spaniol6: Yes, I noticed I had it reversed. Fixed with `!` Thanks

Comment: Both answer is working for me. Which should I accept?

Comment: Whichever one @spaniol6 liked the most :) - he was in first, but `prop` is a much safer choice than `attr` for `disabled`.

Comment: @smartrahat this one is the better answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of checking if the checkbox that was clicked is checked, you should check if any of the checkboxes are checked.  You can do this by selecting all checked checkboxes with `$('.checkbox:checked')` and then checking the length of the returned jQuery object.

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkbox').click(function() {
        if ($('.checkbox:checked').length > 0) {
            $('#off').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#off').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2tp3jhy/)

Comment: Woo Hoo! Thanks brother.

Comment: And plus one for getting in first